# lost access to executable file (file not found)

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I am trying to execute a file that I have recently run. However the system says file is not found?

The file was taking a long time to execute and in the end I had to close the Terminal window that was executing the file, and then reopen it and this problem occured.

Previously I was in the directory `~/poky/build-atmel $` and simply executed the command

```
$ bitbake
```

but the system does no longer recognizes the command.

However, if I try

```
$ ~/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake
```

the file is recognised OK.

What could have happened to the ability of the system to know where the file was and how do I resurrect it. I could add the directory to the `$PATH` variable but there is some other issue here .

I would appreciate any insight into this problem. At present I have just  added the directory to the `PATH` statement to solve the problem.

Thanks
Lachlan

Comment: To know what commands you performed, open a terminal and type `history`. I think as default setting, bash stores the 500 last commands. Maybe you find something there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you had the command in your `PATH` after the setup, but a setup can not make the change to your `PATH` permanent.

Edit `.bashrc` in your home directory and add the following line:

```
export PATH=~/poky/bitbake/bin:$PATH
```

This will add that directory to the `PATH` environment variable permanently.

Comment: @lachlanp I added the useful part of my answer to the answer of Frantique after deleting my answer - ("too localized") - not useful for others.